# Input Edit onclick

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to edit input fields, to circle them, underline them and add 2 images inside the input:
- one at the left 
- one at the right

Each of these action happens `onclick` of a button named circle, underline, up and down.

The circling works somehow but the last 3, I have no clue on how to achieve them. I tried some basic functions `onclick` but it doesn't work

```
 function Underline(){
  document.getElementById('imyinput').input.text-decoration='underline';
}
```

or with other functions that would show the bottom border

```
function Underline(){
  document.getElementById('imyinput').style.border-bottom='solid 1px';
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need `document.getElementById('imyinput').style.textDecoration = 'underline';` and `document.getElementById('imyinput').style.borderBottom = 'solid 1px';`

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow @NeedHelpInFinalProject! Can you add your html/css/js code to help us to have a better understanding and help you.

Comment: i tried to add a snipets but it shows error messages all over the place and won't load here any help ?

Comment: Thank you guys the way i was writing was wrong now it works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var myInput = document.getElementById("inp"),
  tr = document.getElementsByTagName("tr"),
  td = document.getElementsByTagName("td"),
  img1 = document.createElement("img"),
  img2 = document.createElement("img"),
  btn = document.getElementById("circle"),
  remove_images = document.getElementById("remove_img");

img1.src = img2.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/75x32/?text=IMAGE"


btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  td[0].appendChild(img1);
  td[2].appendChild(img2);
  tr[0].style.borderBottom = '2px solid blue';
  tr[0].style.borderTop = '2px solid blue';

})

remove_images.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(td[0].contains(img1))td[0].removeChild(img1);
  if(td[2].contains(img2))td[2].removeChild(img2);
  tr[0].style.borderBottom = 'none';
  tr[0].style.borderTop = 'none';

})
```

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
table{border-collapse:collapse}
td,img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#inp {
  outline:none;
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="inp">
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
 <button id="circle">circle</button>
 <button id="remove_img">remove images</button>
```

Comment: Thank you this answer is quite helpful in making the image inside the input but how can you hide it back ?

Comment: Hi, I updated the answer and added a button to hide the images.

Comment: This is really helpful thanks a lot. it works as i want it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite hard to post a reasonable answer with so few info, but I would try something like

```js
function underline(){
  document.getElementById('imyinput').style.textDecoration='underline';
}

function bottomBorder(){
  document.getElementById('imyinput').style.borderBottom='1px solid red';
}
```

Comment: YET this is exactly what i needed as an answer, i was wrong in the way i wrote textDecorattion style function. Thank you mate.

Comment: I really tried to add my HTML/CSS/JS as a snippets here but i couldn't at all . They show lot of error messages about "Code"